# PHP variable scope help

Tags: php, scope

```
require_once('classes/class.validation.php');

$array = $_POST['array'];
$pass_profanity = false;
$validation = new Validation;
function check_for_profanity($input){
    if(is_array($input)){
        foreach($input as $row){
            if(is_array($row)){
                check_for_profanity($input);
            } else {
                $pass_profanity = $validation->check_for_profanity($row);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $pass_profanity = $validation->check_for_profanity($input);
        return;
    }
    return;
}
check_for_profanity($array);
```

But I get the error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: validation in
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/file.php on line 22
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function check_for_profanity() on a
>   non-object in /Library/WebServer/Documents/file.php
>   on line 2

I can't figure it out, any thoughts???

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Define `$validation` in your function, `check_for_profanity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either gain access to the variable in your function with `global`:

```
function check_for_profanity($input){
    global $validation;
    ...
}
```

Or, the better way would be to retrieve it via a parameter:

```
function check_for_profanity($input, $validation){
    ...
}

check_for_profanity($array, $validation);
```

Read the **[PHP manual - variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)** for more information

Comment: @FraserK Which of the two approaches did you go with from Sascha's answer?

Answer (score 1):

You're defineing $validation = new Validation; outside of the function. Therefore PHP doesn't know it exists.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `global` keyword: [PHP.net: Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

```
$validation = new Validation;
function check_for_profanity($input){

    global $validation;

    //The rest of your function
}
```

Comment: since this is a recursive function will it not be debilitating for the system memory if its being stated as global??

Comment: @FraserK Honestly, I don't know. As far as I am aware, the global keyword essentially references the `$GLOBALS` array. The recursive nature of the function shouldn't have an impact since each call to the global keyword will cause the application to constantly reference the same object. However, I don't know that as a fact.

Comment: okay :) i just realised that the level of recursion will not go that deep anyways :) so it should be fine